# Blur view when button is pressed swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view with a toolbar on the bottom of the view. When clicked - two buttons are displayed. I am trying to achieve when the toolbar is pressed and the buttons are now displayed, the view (or background) becomes blurred/grayed out, except for the newly produced items.

I attached a screenshot of the desired effect I am aiming for.

```
struct UserDashController: View {
    
   // @State private var showMealView = false
    @State private var showSettingsView = false
    @State private var showAddViews = false

    @State private var angle: Double = 0
    
    init(){
        UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
               Text("Blue me Please")
                    .frame(width: 400, height:600)
                    .background(.orange)
            }
            //sets setting bar top right
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        VStack{
                            Button(action: {
                                showSettingsView.toggle()
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
                                    .font(.title3)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                            }
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showSettingsView){
                                JournalEntryMain()
                            }
                        }
                   }
                    
                   // sets add meal option bottom/center
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {

                        //displaying add meal and recipe icons when clicked
                        HStack{

                            Button(action: {
                                angle += 90
                                showAddViews.toggle()

                            }) {

                                if showAddViews {
                                    VStack{
                                        AddToolbar(showAddOptions: $showAddViews)
                                            .offset(y:-50)
                                    }

                                }

                            Image(systemName: "plus.square")
                                .opacity(showAddViews ? 0.5 : 1)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle))
                                .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.25), value: angle)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Buttons that appear  when toolbar is pressed**

```
 struct AddToolbar: View {
    
    @Binding var showAddOptions: Bool
    @State var showMealView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack{
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    showMealView.toggle()
                }){
                    VStack{
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .background(Circle()
                        .fill(.gray)
                        .frame(width:50, height:50))
                    .padding(3)
                
                Text("Meal")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showMealView){
                    JournalEntryMain()
                }
            }
            VStack{
                Image(systemName: "text.book.closed")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.title)
                    .background(Circle()
                        .fill(.gray)
                        .frame(width:50, height:50))
                    .padding(3)
                
                Text("Recipe")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            .offset(y: -50)
            }
        .frame(height:150)
        }
    }
```

**Desired Effect**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your desired effect example, partially because in the UI screenshot you attached, the background isn't blurred, it's just darkened. So, the following answer isn't tailored to your specific example but still should be able to help.

Let's say whatever variable you're using to determine whether or not to show the toolbar is `showSettingsView`. You could put the following modifiers on your **background** view:

- To **blur**:   `.blur(showSettingsView ? 0.5 : 0.0)`
- To **darken**: `.brightness(showSettingsView ? -0.5 : 0.0)`

Obviously just replace "0.5" with whatever number feels best.